# multiple filters based on checkbox and divs id's and classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

The idea is to filter divs by comparing dynamically generated classes for divs and dynamically generated id's for checkboxes, where only divs with classes matching id's of checked checkboxes would show.

First subnav filters everything fine. However, subnav2 dosen't do anything.

Simplified html of it

```
<div class="itemswrap">
  <div class="inditem dynamic1 dynamic12"></div>
  <div class="inditem dynamic2 dynamic22"></div>
  <div class="inditem dynamic3 dynamic32"></div>
  <div class="inditem dynamic2 dynamic42"></div>
</div>


<ul class="subnav">
  <li class="lifilter">
    <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="dynamic1" />
    <label for="dynamic1">whatever label</label>
  </li>
  <li class="lifilter">
    <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="dynamic2" />
    <label for="dynamic1">whatever label</label>
  </li>
  <li class="lifilter">
    <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="dynamic3" />
    <label for="dynamic1">whatever label</label>
  </li>
</ul> 

<ul class="subnav2">
  <li class="lifilter2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck2" id="dynamic12" />
    <label for="dynamic12">whatever label</label>
  </li>
  <li class="lifilter2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck2" id="dynamic22" />
    <label for="dynamic12">whatever label</label>
  </li>
  <li class="lifilter2">
    <input type="checkbox2" class="filtercheck2" id="dynamic32" />
    <label for="dynamic12">whatever label</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the js i've got so far.

```
  var $filters = $('.filtercheck').change(function() {
  var $items = $('.inditem').hide();
  var filters = $filters.filter(':checked').map(function() {
    return '.' + this.id;
  }).get();
  if (filters.length) {
    $items.filter(filters.join()).show();
  } else {
    $items.show();
  }
});

  var $filtersb = $('.filtercheck2').change(function() {
  var $itemsb = $('.inditem').hide();
  var filtersb = $filtersb.filter(':checked').map(function() {
    return '.' + this.id;
  }).get();
  if (filtersb.length) {
    $itemsb.filter(filters.join()).show();
  } else {
    $itemsb.show();
  }
});
```

Comment: this question lacks of a question :-)

Comment: Is '.concernfilter' really '.filtercheck2'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you fixed it but I had created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imelgrat/cb3cco1f/) for your problem, akin to one I had to face in another project. Basically, you create a string from the checked checkboxes IDs and use that to show only those items that match the elements you checked. If no elements are checked, all items are shown (i.e. no filters are applied).

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function()
{
    var list = "";

    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function()
    {
        if(this.checked)
        {
            list = list + '.' + $(this).attr('id');
        }
    });

    if(list !=='')
    {
        $("div.inditem").hide();
        $(list).show();
    }
    else {
        $("div.inditem").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: it does work in the fiddle, but on the site, 2nd filter doesn't work for some reason. Gotta play around with it a little. Btw, there are also drop down navi items with same classes as some of the filtered divs (there is no way to change it). What do you think would be the best way to limit show action to a certain container div here?

Comment: If the filters' div has an ID, you can prepend the #ID to the input[type=checkbox] so that only the items inside that DIV are affected. The same applies to the filtered result items. Just add the DIVs. Without access to the site, I can't really tell why the second filter does not work

Comment: Sorry, @wharry  The site asks for a password. I can't see the actual password. You may want to send it using the chat tool to avoid making it public

Comment: your code worked. The problem was on my side. thank you!